# How to implement gain and offset in a single opamp?

Tags: analog, signal-processing, instrumentation-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp, dc-offset

I tried designer here in [this page](http://earmark.net/gesr/opamp/gain_offset.htm). But my particular case (Case 2) seems not working in the page.
Then I Read [this document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa097/sloa097.pdf?ts=1619329572365&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) and my case there, is section 4. But my calculation results are not producing intended result in LT Spice. I am making some mistake somewhere, which I cannot locate. Can somebody provide me the solution?
I am using Op-amp  LM324 with single supply 12V.
My input signal spans from 4.5V to 6.5V. I need to span the output signal from 3V to 10V. Reference voltage I can provide is 5V.
Circuit I follow is here
[image: Circuit]
Thanks.
Here is the circuit I tried. The output spans from 7.5V to 10.5V with these values. The values I calculated from  the Document I referenced above.
[image]

Comment: How can we help you to locate the error you have made without knowing what you did? What is the problem? What are your "intended results"? The solution is a basic one - determine the feedback factor.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: 'Intended result' is for a input of 4.5V to 6.5V, I should Get 3V to 10V output.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us what exactly you are trying to do, what you've attempted, and how what you attempted isn't giving you the results you intended? I'm not sure what you are asking either.

Comment: @UroBorosTech Try, for example, in your first (not second) diagram: \$R_1=145\:\Omega\$, \$R_{g_2}=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$,  \$R_{g_1}=3.857\:\text{k}\Omega\$, and \$R_f=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Tell me what you get at your output. But before you try that, change your ground reference that \$R_{g_2}\$ goes to, so that it connects to \$+12\:\text{V}\$, instead. (I'm assuming that \$V_{ref}=+5\:\text{V}\$.)

Comment: @jonk can you clarify the resistor references please? There seems to be 2 values given for R1.

Comment: @UroBorosTech I fixed the comment.

Comment: @UroBorosTech The basics are: (1) work out the nodal equation for where the three resistors meet up (you know that you have available to you +12, +5, and 0 volts as possible references); and, (2) work out what Vout is. From these, you also know your gain (3.5) and your offset (-12.75 V.) So you can use those values, as well, to establish relationships between various resistors. From all that, you can set one or two of the resistor values and get the remaining from there.

Comment: @jonk  Thank you very much
Now I am getting the intended result in simulator. 4.5V from 6.5V input gives 3.5V to 10.5V output. That is what I want.
May I know How the values are derived? The Texas Document I referenced above is saying something else. They say that R1>>Rg2, but we are doing opposite here.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @UroBorosTech I've added an answer that may help out.

Comment: Do you need the output to vary continuously with the input, or do you only need a high / low level?

Comment: @jonk Thanks. I am getting the results ok.

Comment: @Reinderien I need the output varies within the limits continuously.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at a simplified diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXIaaw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's set \$R_f=68\:\text{k}\Omega\$.
You know that \$1+\frac{R_f}{R_{th}}=3.5\$, which is your desired gain. So it follows that \$R_{th}=27.2\:\text{k}\Omega\$. If the input is \$4.5\:\text{V}\$ then the output is \$3.0\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_{th}=5.1\:\text{V}\$. Similarly, if the input is \$6.5\:\text{V}\$ then the output is \$10.0\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_{th}=5.1\:\text{V}\$, again. So we know what \$V_{th}\$ is!

To achieve that, we can use either the \$+12\:\text{V}\$ and \$0\:\text{V}\$ rails or else the \$+12\:\text{V}\$ and \$+5\:\text{V}\$ rails. In my comment I chose the latter pair. But in reality it's better to choose the former pair.

Let's expand the above diagram now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqiwir.png)</sup>

We know we want \$5.1\:\text{V}\$ from the \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ divider. I've set \$R_1=27\:\text{k}\Omega\$, arbitrarily. So I can work out that \$R_2\approx 19.957 \:\text{k}\Omega\$. Round that up to \$R_2= 20 \:\text{k}\Omega\$. From this, I can work out that \$R_3\approx 15.711\:\text{k}\Omega\$. If we round that down to \$R_3\approx 15\:\text{k}\Omega\$, the gain will be just a bit high. But perhaps acceptable.

So the final diagram is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOHcdA.png)</sup>

That's not all that complicated. The output will be about \$2.94\:\text{V}\$ when the input is \$4.5\:\text{V}\$ and about \$10.08\:\text{V}\$ when the input is \$6.5\:\text{V}\$. As I said, the gain will be just a bit high. But this is pretty close. And feel free to adjust resistor values as you see fit to make this better.

Keep in mind that resistors have tolerances. So while my calculations above may seem close, you really need to apply *worst-case* scenarios here to see just how bad it may actually be given any particular resistor accuracy estimate.

For example, assuming exact values you'd anticipate that the node where the three resistors meet would have exactly \$V_{min}=4.8433735\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_{max}=5.7108434\:\text{V}\$ with those resistor values and given your input voltage range. However, 1% resistors may yield:

$$\begin{align*}
4.8092322\:\text{V}\le V_{min}&\le 4.8778686\:\text{V}\\\\
5.6737453\:\text{V}\le V_{max}&\le 5.7476844\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

With similar shifts in the resulting output offset and gain.

Just keep all this in mind. It is annoyingly difficult to get precision values at the output, like this.

Comment: Good answer. One but: Vref is slightly more complicated than just a voltage divider. It would be better to represent that as a Thevenin equivalent source. The parallel combination of the two voltage divider resistors gets added to R3.

Comment: @KD9PDP Exactly. And just what I did. If you check the calculation results. (I didn't disclose all the details I applied.) Unless I misunderstand you...

Comment: Nice, I didn't do the calculation myself so I wasn't sure.

Comment: The risk here is that you need a clean, stable 12V reference. The only such reference the OP guarantees is 5V.

Answer (score 5):

Your design goals are to have

- \$V_{out} = 3\$ when \$V_{in} = 4.5\$
- \$V_{out} = 10\$ when \$V_{in} = 6.5\$

Solving for a linear equation, you want

\$V_{out} = \frac{7}{2}V_{in} - 12.75\$

An often used Op-Amp topology for amplification and level shifting looks like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIRowv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To find the resistor values, we start by defining two voltages.

- to make \$V_{out} = V_{ref}\$, \$V_{in}\$ must equal \$\frac{35.5}{7}\$ (Calculated from the equation \$V_{out} = \frac{7}{2}V_{in} - 12.75\$) . Call \$V_r = \frac{35.5}{7}\$.
- to make \$V_{out} = 0\$, \$V_{in}\$ must equal \$\frac{25.5}{7}\$. Call \$V_0 = \frac{25.5}{7}\$.

When \$V_{in} = V_r, V_{out} = V_{ref}\$ so the voltage at the inverting input is \$\frac{R1 \cdot V_{ref} + R2 \cdot V_{ref}}{R1+R2} = V_{ref}\$, so the voltage at the non-inverting input must also be \$V_{ref}\$

Knowing this, we can calculate the ratio between R3 and R4.

\$V_r\frac{R4}{R3+R4} = V_{ref}\$

\$\frac{R4}{R3+R4} = \frac{V_{ref}}{V_r} = \frac{35}{35.5}\$

\$\frac{R3}{R4} = \frac{0.5}{35} = \frac{1}{70}\$

(We may pick R3 = 1k\$\Omega\$ and R4= 70k\$\Omega\$)

Next we observe that when \$V_{in} = V_0\$, the voltage at the Op-Amp inputs must be \$V_0\frac{R4}{R3+R4} = \frac{70}{71}\frac{25.5}{7} = \frac{255}{71}\$

From this we can calculate the ratio between R1 and R2.

\$V_{ref}\frac{R2}{R1+R2} = \frac{255}{71}\$

\$\frac{R2}{R1+R2} = \frac{51}{71}\$

\$\frac{R1}{R2} = \frac{20}{51}\$

We might choose R1 = 20k\$\Omega\$ and R2 = 51k\$\Omega\$

When we plug all four resistor values into the CircuitLab schematic above, and run a DC simulation, we find that the original design goals are exactly met.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9zSp2.png)</sup>

- \$V_{out} = 3\$ when \$V_{in} = 4.5\$
- \$V_{out} = 10\$ when \$V_{in} = 6.5\$

Comment: One disadvantage of this topology compared with that of the other two answers is that the input impedance will no longer be based on the op-amp, but will be R3 + R4; in your case 71k.

Comment: @Reinderien Agreed. But it has the advantage that the reference voltage is what was specified in the question. No particular input impedance was specified.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution with only three resistors is feasible. First, a warning: you say that

> Reference voltage I can provide is 5V

This is a hair too low to be used as a reference for this topology. The minimum reference voltage is 5.1V. Here I've shown 12V - your supply - used as the reference; I can only assume that it's suitable in terms of noise and accuracy.

The equations governing this topology are

$$a = \frac {R_1} {R_3}$$
$$b = \frac {R_1} {R_4}$$
$$b =
\left( \frac { V_{oh} - V_{ol}} {V_{ih} - V_{il}} - 1 \right)
\left( 1 - \frac {V_{il}} {V_{ref}} \right)
+ \frac {V_{ol} - V_{il}} {V_{ref}} = \frac {23} {16}
$$
$$
a = \frac { V_{oh} - V_{ol}} {V_{ih} - V_{il}} - b - 1 = \frac {17} {16}
$$

With suitable choice of E96 resistors you can get very close to your output bounds - in this case 3.052V and 10.00V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f33T7V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: simulation]